# How to debug a Java program where errors are output at compilation?

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop

Error while compiling for For loop

Class For {

```
    public static void main (String[]args){

    if (args.length == 0) {

            System.out.println ("Please enter a number between 1-99");

        } else  if (x >= 100) { 

System.out.println("Error Invalid Number.");

    } else {

        for (int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);x < 100; x++) {


    System.out.println (x);
    }
}
```

}
}

What Am I Doing Wrong?? Please refer to the attachment for error details...[Error that I am getting while compiling the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pioyr.jpg)

My error is:

cannot find symbol

> else   if (x >= 100)

Comment: And that error says... ?

Comment: A compilation error is the compiler's way of telling you what the problem is.  Read the error.  (If I were to *guess*, your second `if` statement is incomplete.  You forgot to include a condition.  And you added a condition to your `else` statement, which doesn't make sense.)

Comment: And then search for that specific error message.

Comment: I have added the details of the error you have supplied so far, Sayury. Despite the downvotes you have received, I would be pleased if you would edit the question and paste in the **exact** error message, directly from your console. It should refer to line numbers where it sees the error(s).

Comment: What Am I Doing Wrong now?? Please refer to the attachment link (I have updated above) for error details.. Class For { public static void main (String[]args){ if (args.length == 0) { System.out.println ("Please enter a number between 1-99"); } else if (x >= 100) { System.out.println("Error Invalid Number."); } else { for (int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);x < 100; x++) { System.out.println (x); } } } }

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your else clause.

```
else (x >= 100)
```

The condition should always be after "if" (or else if), and never after the "else" keyword. Also, as @EJoshuaS mentioned, you have no condition for your

```
else if {
```

Which also triggers a compilation error.

Edit:

In your new source code, you define

```
else { 
    for (x = ...)
```

But you reference x before:

```
else if (x >= 100) {
```

Since x is not defined in that scope, you're getting a compilation error.

Hint:
After verifying that you have an argument for the program, define

```
int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
```

And only then do the rest of the flow.

Comment: On a similar note, he also has "else  if" with absolutely no condition

Comment: I am still getting an error while compiling after editing my code as mentioned above. class For {


        public static void main (String[]args){
   
  if (args.length == 0) {
    
    System.out.println ("Please enter a number between 1-99");
    
   } else if (x >= 100) {
    
 System.out.println("Error Invalid Number.");
 
        } else {
   
   for (int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);x < 100; x++) {
   
   
        System.out.println (x);
  }
 }
  }
}

Comment: What is the new error you're getting?

Comment: I am still getting an "error saying cannot find symbol"  while compiling after editing my code as mentioned above. class For {


        public static void main (String[]args){
   
  if (args.length == 0) {
    
    System.out.println ("Please enter a number between 1-99");
    
   } else if (x >= 100) {
    
 System.out.println("Error Invalid Number.");
 
        } else {
   
   for (int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);x < 100; x++) {
   
   
        System.out.println (x);
  }
 }
  }
}

Comment: @sayury I've updated my answer.

Comment: What Am I Doing Wrong now?? Please refer to the attachment link (I have updated above) for error details..                                                                        Class For {


        public static void main (String[]args){
   
  if (args.length == 0) {
    
    System.out.println ("Please enter a number between 1-99");
    
   } else if (x >= 100) { 
    
 System.out.println("Error Invalid Number.");
 
        } else {
   
   for (int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);x < 100; x++) {
   
   
        System.out.println (x);
  }
 }
  }
}